# JQuery Sortable Issue - First "draggable" element does not cooperate (all others do)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am having an issue where my sortable grid is working properly aside from the first element which does not seem to want to work with the rest of the gridded elements. I cannot deduce why this is as I'm very new to JS/JQuery so any help is very much appreciated!

Below is my JS...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".topic-container").droppable({
        accept: ".draggable"
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#draggable").draggable({
            snap: ".topic-container",
            snapMode: "inner",
            snapTolerance: 10,
            grid: [100, 50],
            revert: "invalid",
            opacity: 0.7,
            refreshPositions: true,
            scroll: true
        });
    });

    $(".topic-container").droppable({
        hoverClass: "droppable-highlight"
    });

    $(".topic-container").droppable({
        tolerance: "pointer"
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#droppable, #droppable2").sortable({
            connectWith: ".topic-container"
        }).disableSelection();
    });

});
```

And my HTML...

```
<section class="teir-sorter">
    <h2>Teir 1 Categories</h2>
    <div class="topic-container" id="droppable">

       <div class="topic-card draggable" id="draggable"></div>
       <div class="topic-card draggable" id="draggable"></div>
       <div class="topic-card draggable" id="draggable"></div>
       <div class="topic-card draggable" id="draggable"></div>
       <div class="topic-card draggable" id="draggable"></div>
       <div class="topic-card draggable" id="draggable"></div>
       <div class="topic-card draggable" id="draggable"></div>
       <div class="topic-card draggable" id="draggable"></div>
       <div class="topic-card draggable" id="draggable"></div>
       <div class="topic-card draggable" id="draggable"></div>
       <div class="topic-card draggable" id="draggable"></div>

  </div>

  <h2>Teir 2 Categories</h2>
  <div class="topic-container" id="droppable2">

  </div>
  </section>
```

I cannot see any reason why the first element would behave so strangely when the rest of them work. If I drag them into the second droppable area they continue working fine, it's just the one spot in first droppable area (id = droppable1). Not only does the draggable item not sort or snap correctly, but the space it took up becomes unusable by the rest of the draggable elements. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I did just realize all my draggable elements have the same ID as soon as I posted. Could this be the issue? Checking now...

Comment: yes that can be the issue, if you have duplicate ids, id selector will consider only the first element with that id.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I tried to use a class selector vs. the ID selector, then changed all the IDs to something unique, none of the draggable elements worked anymore. So I changed the selector back to the `"#draggable"` ID and kept all the IDs unique. Now none of the IDs match the selector, and it works perfectly. So I going to assume that when you add `.sortable` to your `.droppable` element, all parameters for the `.draggable` elements become moot. (i.e. grid, snap, tolerance, etc.). Can anyone confirm this? Thanks!